# Can you patent product based on another companies IP

Tags: intellectual-property, patents

If I had a prototype for a product that was heavily based on another company's IP is there any way I can get legal protection for the product's design?

I don't want to go and sell the prototype to the company only for them to say no to me then make it themselves.

Comment: You want protection for aspects of the prototype's design that are above and beyond the company's IP? Are these esthetic elements or functional elements/implementation details?

Comment: aaahh ok so I could protect, say, the functional elements i.e. this scanned here, that element held down by this magnet system, this bit of software handles scanned information like X.

Comment: Separate bits are conceivably, but unlikely, to be protectable.